# How to save data into my Production/Development Servers using Laravel 4 ?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, phpmyadmin

I want to keep track on log-in info of my users.
In my Sign-In function, somewhere at the end I did this

```
if(Auth::check()){
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->last_logged_in = Input::get('created_at');
    $user->logged_in_count = $user->logged_in_count + 1 ;
    $user->is_online = '1';
    $user->save();
    }
```

The problem is that it's work locally, when I check it on phpMyAdmin.
I use WAMP Server.

BUT It's doesn't work on my production/dev server that running on Linux OS.

This line didn't get save on the server.

```
$user->last_logged_in = Input::get('created_at');
```

and also this line

```
$user->is_online = '1';
```

But the logged_in_count work

```
$user->logged_in_count = $user->logged_in_count + 1 ;
```

Why??? Is it because they're running on different OS ? 
The ugly part is that some of them get save, and some of them doesn't.

Did someone come across this issue before ?

Huge `THANK` for any tips/suggestions on this!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might have [strict mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-other-changes-strict-mode.html) enabled in your production MySQL settings.

You can turn this off in the MySQL config file, if you don't have access try casting your variables correctly (so use `intval` to ensure an integer on a numeric field etc).